# Hibernate JPA not executing import.sql on classpath

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have a Hibernate JPA project that has an `import.sql` file on the classpath.  I have tried a number of things to get it working.  My persistence.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.1"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="SNAPSHOTPU"
        transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/PostgresqlDS</jta-data-source>
        <class>net.example.Actor</class>
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action"
                value="drop-and-create" />
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop" />
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files" value="import.sql" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

I have also tried it without the `hibernate.hbm2ddl.*` stuff because this is JPA, but neither seems to work.  My import.sql is in `src/main/resources` and this is a Maven project.

I have one valid SQL statement in the file:

`insert into actors values (1, 'Test Import.sql');`

I even tried a blank line at the beginning of the file as I saw someone suggest.  I have debug turned on for Hibernate and can see it running the DDL commands in the log to create the tables, but I do not see anything about `import.sql` or about the insert statement in the file.

Why isn't this working?

**EDIT**

@Baldurian got it right below, here is what works (in the persistence.xml):

```
<properties>
    <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
    <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action"
        value="drop-and-create" />
    <property name="javax.persistence.sql-load-script-source"
        value="/import.sql" />
</properties>
```

Comment: very important note  import.sql is in src/main/resources

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try (change javax.persistence.sql-load-script-source path accordingly):

```
<properties>
    <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
    <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="drop-and-create" />
    <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.create-source" value="metadata-then-script"/>
    <property name="javax.persistence.sql-load-script-source" value="/import.sql"/>
</properties>
```